# "socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use" in heterogeneous example on veins-lte

Tags: omnet++

I'm trying to change the application type in the veins-lte "heterogeneous" example and I get the following error (in the SUMO log):

> "socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use"

I tried with different traffic configurations in SUMO or with different applications, but I always get the same error. I'm able to run the the example, but it stops in a few seconds without showing any errors on OMNeT++.

Here's my `omnetpp.ini:`

```
    [General]
cmdenv-express-mode = true
cmdenv-autoflush = true
cmdenv-status-frequency = 10000000s

#tkenv-default-config = debug
#tkenv-default-run = 1
sim-time-limit = 30s
tkenv-image-path = bitmaps
ned-path = .

network = scenario

##########################################################
#            Simulation parameters                       #
##########################################################
debug-on-errors = true
print-undisposed = false


**.scalar-recording = true
**.vector-recording = true

#record-eventlog = true


**.debug = false
**.coreDebug = false

*.playgroundSizeX = 20000m
*.playgroundSizeY = 20000m
*.playgroundSizeZ = 50m


##########################################################
# Annotation parameters                                  #
##########################################################
*.annotations.draw = false

##########################################################
# Obstacle parameters                                    #
##########################################################
*.obstacles.debug = false

##########################################################
#            WorldUtility parameters                     #
##########################################################
*.world.useTorus = false
*.world.use2D = false

##########################################################
#            TraCIScenarioManager parameters             #
##########################################################
*.manager.updateInterval = 0.1s
*.manager.host = "localhost"
*.manager.port = 9999
*.manager.moduleType = "org.car2x.veins.modules.heterogeneous.HeterogeneousCar"
*.manager.moduleName = "node"
*.manager.moduleDisplayString = ""
*.manager.autoShutdown = true
*.manager.margin = 25
*.manager.launchConfig = xmldoc("heterogeneous.launchd.xml")

##########################################################
#            11p specific parameters                     #
#                                                        #
#                    NIC-Settings                        #
##########################################################
*.connectionManager.pMax = 20mW
*.connectionManager.sat = -89dBm
*.connectionManager.alpha = 2.0
*.connectionManager.carrierFrequency = 5.890e9 Hz
*.connectionManager.sendDirect = true

*.**.nic80211p.mac1609_4.useServiceChannel = false

*.**.nic80211p.mac1609_4.txPower = 20mW
*.**.nic80211p.mac1609_4.bitrate = 18Mbps

*.**.nic80211p.phy80211p.sensitivity = -89dBm
*.**.nic80211p.phy80211p.maxTXPower = 10mW
*.**.nic80211p.phy80211p.useThermalNoise = true
*.**.nic80211p.phy80211p.thermalNoise = -110dBm
*.**.nic80211p.phy80211p.decider = xmldoc("config.xml")
*.**.nic80211p.phy80211p.analogueModels = xmldoc("config.xml")
*.**.nic80211p.phy80211p.usePropagationDelay = true


##########################################################
#                      Mobility                          #
##########################################################
*.node[*].veinsmobilityType = "org.car2x.veins.modules.mobility.traci.TraCIMobility"
*.node[*].mobilityType = "TraCIMobility"
*.node[*].mobilityType.debug = true
*.node[*].veinsmobilityType.debug = true
*.node[*].veinsmobility.x = 0
*.node[*].veinsmobility.y = 0
*.node[*].veinsmobility.z = 1.895
*.node[*0].veinsmobility.accidentCount = 0
*.node[*0].veinsmobility.accidentStart = 75s
*.node[*0].veinsmobility.accidentDuration = 30s

###########################
# LTE specific parameters #
###########################
**.node[*].masterId = 1
**.node[*].macCellId = 1
**.eNodeB1.macCellId = 1
**.eNodeB1.macNodeId = 1
**.eNodeBCount = 1
**.configurator.config = xmldoc("topology-config.xml")
#*.server.numUdpApps = 1
#*.server.udpApp[0].typename = "SimpleServerApp"
#*.server.udpApp[0].localPort = 4242

#============= Application Setup ============= 

##########################################################
#                    WaveAppLayer                        #
##########################################################
*.node[*].applType = "UDPVideoStreamCli"
*.node[*].appl.serverAddress = "server"         #
*.node[*].appl.localPort = 9999
*.node[*].appl.serverPort = 3088                #
*.node[*].appl.startTime = uniform(0s, 0.02s)
##########################################################
#                       RSU SETTINGS                     #
##########################################################
*.server.applType = "UDPVideoStreamSvr"
*.server.appl.videoSize = 10MiB
*.server.appl.localPort = 3088
*.server.appl.sendInterval = 20ms
*.server.appl.packetLen = ${packetLen = 1000B }

**.mtu = 10000B


##########################################################
#                    channel parameters                  #
##########################################################
**.channelControl.pMax = 10W
**.channelControl.alpha = 1.0
**.channelControl.carrierFrequency = 2100e+6Hz

################### RLC parameters #######################
#**.fragmentSize=75B
#**.timeout=50s
################### MAC parameters #######################
**.mac.queueSize = ${queue = 2MiB}
**.mac.maxBytesPerTti = ${maxBytesPerTti = 3MiB}
**.mac.macDelay.result-recording-modes = all
**.mac.macThroughput.result-recording-modes = all

# Schedulers
**.mac.schedulingDisciplineDl = ${scheduler = "MAXCI"} #MAXCI, DRR, PF
**.mac.schedulingDisciplineUl = ${scheduler}

################ PhyLayer parameters #####################
**.nic.phy.usePropagationDelay = true
**.nic.phy.channelModel=xmldoc("config_channel.xml")

################ Feedback parameters #####################
**.feedbackComputation = xmldoc("config_channel.xml")

# UEs
**.enableHandover = false

################# Deployer parameters #######################
# UEs attached to eNB
**.fbDelay = 1

# General
**.deployer.positionUpdateInterval = 0.1s
**.deployer.broadcastMessageInterval = 1s

# RUs
**.deployer.numRus = 0
**.deployer.ruRange = 50
**.deployer.ruTxPower = "50,50,50;"
**.deployer.ruStartingAngle = 0deg
**.deployer.antennaCws = "2;" # !!MACRO + RUS (numRus + 1)

# AMC
**.deployer.numRbDl = ${RB = 100}
**.deployer.numRbUl = ${RB}
**.deployer.rbyDl = 12
**.deployer.rbyUl = 12
**.deployer.rbxDl = 7
**.deployer.rbxUl = 7
**.deployer.rbPilotDl = 3
**.deployer.rbPilotUl = 0
**.deployer.signalDl = 1
**.deployer.signalUl = 1
**.deployer.numBands = 1
**.deployer.numPreferredBands = 1

############### AMC MODULE PARAMETERS ###############
**.rbAllocationType = "localized"
**.mac.amcMode = "AUTO"
**.feedbackType = "ALLBANDS"
**.feedbackGeneratorType = "IDEAL"
**.maxHarqRtx = 3
**.pfAlpha = 0.95
**.pfTmsAwareDL = false
**.numUe = ${numUEs=1000}

############### Transmission Power ##################
**.ueTxPower = 26
**.microTxPower = 20
**.eNodeBTxPower = 45

[Config nodebug]
description = "default settings"
**.debug = false
**.coreDebug = false
*.annotations.draw = false

[Config debug]
description = "(very slow!) draw and print additional debug information"
**.debug = true
**.coreDebug = true
*.annotations.draw = true
```

I'd appreciate any help, I really don't know how to solve it... Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not familiar with omnet++, but this appears to be a system level error.  Have you checked that no other application is listening on or connected using TCP or UDP ports 9999 and 3088?

Comment: I tried changing both of them but the error is still there...

Comment: in your (newly pasted) ini file, I notice you are trying to change settings of the `WaveAppLayer`. Are you sure this is what you want to achieve? You say _"I'm trying to change the application type in the veins-lte"_ , I assume you are referring to the application running on the `eNodeB` and/or the `Vehicle` by that? Or am I wrong?

Comment: I was trying to do something like this:https://github.com/floxyz/veins-lte/blob/master/simulte/simulations/demo/omnetpp.ini to have video streaming traffic between eNodeB and the moving nodes. That's why I changed that from "TraCIDemo11p" to "UDPVideoStreamCli"... Anyway, I'm new with OMNeT++ so maybe I got it wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get the following error (in the SUMO log):
>
> > "socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use"

If I am not mistaken, this is an error message from Python. It is not an OMNeT++ error, nor is it an error message that SUMO would output.

My guess is that you are getting the error message when you are trying to run [sumo-launchd.py](http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/sumo-launchd/), the script that launches SUMO when needed by OMNeT++.

There are two possible reasons I can see:

1. You are trying to run two instances of sumo-launchd.py in parallel. This is not necessary. Having only one instance running is enough.
2. Some other program is using the same address and port (TCP port 9999). Independent of whether you are running this program knowingly or [if it is malware](http://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=9999), either shutting down the conflicting program or changing the sumo-launchd.py port number will help. See the [sumo-launchd.py documentation](http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/sumo-launchd/) for how to change its port number.

Comment: OK, I didn't realize I was trying to see errors using sumo-launchd.py, while it was already running... anyway, it's still not working...   
Do you know if it's possible to change the application type in veins-lte? I've searched and I couldn't find anything similar implemented

Comment: Sounds like your original question was resolved. If you have another question, kindly close this one and open another. This helps other people find answers to their questions more easily.